# Select all the dates between two chosen dates

Tags: php, mysql

I am building an app on php,mysql which is related to events.  This is a specific feature where the user will repeat an activity/event . The user will select a start date and an end date . Now i am trying to figure out how to calculate the dates between those two selected dates. I am using jquery's datepicker for date selection .

```
     $start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['start_date']));
   $end_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['end_date']));
```

Datediff doesn't seem to do the work as it only gives the difference between two dates . I want all the dates between those two dates .

Would be great if someone could advice as per how to go about this .

Comment: What do you want to do with those dates?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

By this way You can fetch the dates between two dates

```
   $start_date = strtotime($_POST['start_date']);
    $end_date = strtotime($_POST['end_date']);

    // Loop between timestamps, 24 hours at a time
    for ( $i = $start_date ; $i <= $end_date ; $i = $i + 86400 ) {
              echo   date( 'Y-m-d', $i )."<br>";          

    }
```

Comment: This is the output ---> 1970-01-01

For the chosen dates betweeen : 
2015-01-29--->2015-03-29

Comment: Test properly...It returns all the dates between 29th jan and 29th march

Comment: Just copy and paste my code in a php and try

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to use DateTime objects

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Istanbul");
$dt = new DateTime("10-01-2014");
$diff = $dt->diff(new Datetime("12-01-2014"));
for($i = 1; $i <= $diff->days; $i++) {
   $nextdate = $dt->modify("+1 day");
   echo $nextdate->format("d-m-Y"); echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: Did you test yourself before posting here????

Comment: This doesnt seem to work at all ....$dt = new DateTime($_POST['start_date']); and $diff = $dt->diff($_POST['end_date']); make no sense as they throw blank outputs...

Comment: They are sample code please read the DateTime [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
I dont know what your start_date field contains so you may need to change little bit this sample code

Comment: and also valid datetime formats for constructor of DateTime http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Comment: I changed the code to correct one you can understand how it works now

Answer (score -1):

```
function createDateRangeArray($strDateFrom,$strDateTo)
    {       
        $aryRange=array();

        $iDateFrom=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateFrom,5,2),     substr($strDateFrom,8,2),substr($strDateFrom,0,4));
        $iDateTo=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateTo,5,2),     substr($strDateTo,8,2),substr($strDateTo,0,4));

        if ($iDateTo>=$iDateFrom)
        {
            array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom)); // first entry
            while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo)
            {
                $iDateFrom+=86400; // add 24 hours
                array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
            }
        }
        return $aryRange;
    }
```

Found the above solution and it works great. Thanks everyone for the time and advice.

Comment: I really recommend you to create your own function base on my comment. I edited the code you will understand now how it works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000840/php-mysql-select-all-the-dates-between-two-chosen-dates/28000930#28000930